# How do you get the window bottom Y accounting for zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose you have an element with a `position: absolute` (**not** `position: fixed`) property. How do you compute, with JavaScript, the `top` value such element must have so that it is positioned exactly on the bottom of the screen? `window.innerHeight + window.scrollY` works, but doesn't account for zoom.

Comment: How do you use `zoom` it's 1`zoom` css? or `scale`?

Comment: I don't think that it is the zoom that causes the problem, the position of the element will be set in relation to it's parent element. so `window.innerHeight + window.scrollY` cannot set the position correct, unless of course your element is a direct child of the body. Can you post some code so we can see exactly what you are trying to do?